# Error during xml file creation due to space in file path

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am creating a xml file. Having no prob with this code.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
String fileName="D:\\Doc\\File.xml";
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(fileName));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

But if the path is

```
String fileName="D:\\My Doc\\File.xml";
```

Then it is throwing error.

```
XML-22110: (Fatal Error) Invalid StreamResult set in TransformerHandler.
```

I think the space in the file path is creating the problem. How to solve it?

Comment: I have no idea if the space is your problem, but if so you can fix it by escaping the space with a single \ such that: `String fileName="D:\\My\ Doc\\File.xml";`. I'm not currently on my work machine so I can't check if that's the case but I hope it helps.

Comment: @norfavrell compiler error is coming

Comment: @SweetDream, can you post exception stack trace? It might be useful.

Comment: @defaultlocale only the above error is printed in console

Comment: @SweetDream, have you tried to catch throwable and print stack trace? It's helpful to know error type and stack trace here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that the space is *not* the problem.  I just ran this code and it worked perfectly:

```
package io;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * FileWithSpace description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 7/24/12 5:03 AM
 */
public class FileWithSpace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File dir = new File("J:\\Path With Spaces");
            boolean exists = dir.mkdirs();
            if (exists) {
                File f = new File("J:\\Path With Spaces\\test.txt");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
                ps.println("This is a test");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I did create the directory before writing the file to it.  Does `C:\\My Docs` exist before you start?  If not, add that `mkdirs()` step, as shown.  My simple example fails if I don't create the directory before creating the `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat the file as a FileOutputStream. If you don't do that, the file-name will be treated as a URI.

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream( absolutePath ) );
Source input = new DOMSource( XMLDoc );
transformer.transform(input, output);
```

NB: To answer the above as well: The problem is specific to the XML-transformer. It does not occur when you simply create a file for writing.